# Modular Programming for Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm at the moment programming a modular application with Laravel.

It's a little bit like learning project for me, creating stable software with a good code quality.

I'm working with Laravel 5 at the moment and my approach was as following:

I created a package directory in the root of my Laravel app, where I've got a normal ServiceProvider and a Controller as well as a routes.php.
My idea behind this was, that this package will be a bit like a 'Bootloader' ...

So, I've also created a module directory under the root directory of laravel where my own modules are residing.

So, what my Bootloader does at the moment is searching in my modules directory for a module.json file, where the information about my modules are written. It's also planned to be able to active and deactivate this modules.

So you could actually say, that my Bootloader is the brain of all those modules ... My problem at the moment is, that I don't know how to make my modules controller (which are under modules/modulename/src) familiar with my IoC container.

I really don't want to create ServiceProvider for each of my modules, so I hope that I can handle this from my Bootloader Package.

If there are any questions, just go ahaed and ask :)

Really looking forward for your answers!

P.S. : I know that there are already modules out there which provide a similiar functionality, I just want to do it on my own ;)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to ask ?? !!

Comment: My problem at the moment is, that I don't know how to make my modules controller (which are under modules/modulename/src) familiar with my IoC container. So, here I'm trying to dynamically add the controller directory of each module ... and that's where I'm stuck